# Axis labels not neat when being rotated in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make the axis labels neat and appropriately spaced when they are rotated in ggplot2?
Below is an example. The labels become untidy, and the spaces between characters are not evenly placed.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- cbind(
  x = c('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'consectetur adipiscing elit', 'Sed non lacus imperdiet', 'posuere tortor consectetur'),
  y = 1:4
) %>% as.data.frame()

ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=8, family="sans", face="bold", colour="black", angle=30, hjust=1),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=8, family="sans", face="bold", colour="black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Some R graphics devices don't handle rotated text well. `ragg` is a package / graphics device that might help you here. https://ragg.r-lib.org/articles/ragg_quality.html#text

Comment: This issue doesn't arise on my computer - does it occur when you export? It may be specific to settings or technical in nature. I suggest looking into the package Jon Spring mentions

Comment: Indeed, I expect this to be some (windows) device issue. The {ragg} package has better text handling than most other devices.